# Adding fresh herbs in no-knead Bread

Tags: baking, bread, herbs

I am experimenting with the no Knead bread recipe and want to add herbs to the recipe. I have added fresh rosemary (great) and fresh oregano (not so) to the recipe.

What other herbs would you suggest?

Comment: Try using some sage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to choose spices in bread to match or complement the spices in the main dish. For example, garlic salt and parsley to go with a spaghetti/lasagna.

Answer (score 4):

I love a bit of thyme in bread. Pairs well with the rosemary, too.

Answer (score 1):

Basil and pine nuts could be added for a "pesto" version.

While not a herb, you could add chopped olives (and sun dried tomatoes).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried dill and dill seeds and loved the flavour